# How to cluster faces of persons based on facial landmarks?

Tags: image-processing, cluster-analysis, dlib, biometrics, facial-identification

I am getting facial landmarks using dlib. I have dataset of more than 1000 faces. I want to make a comparison of these 1000 images with some unknown image. To decrease the database search time, i want to cluster these 1000images in to 10 different clusters based on the 68 facial landmark features of dlib. Currently, I am clustering based on chin to nose distance of different face images.

Problem: Each image of same person is generating different facial landmarks which is effecting the distance calculated from chin to nose tip. Please find the screenshot of csv  [image]

1. 1st column - Face Image names (same person face with around 25
   samples)
2. 2nd,3rd columns - Kmeans clustered labels and centroids of column
   4
3. 4th - Face chin to nose tip euclidean distances
4. 5th - 68 long dlib facial landmarks seperated as chin, eye ....

Questions:

1. Is it a right way to cluster images based on facial landmarks ?  If not, what is the best way to cluster face images/face groupping to make databse searc more efficient for more images ?

I tried with gender classification, but the accuracy is not good. Tried with face color/Ethnicity classification but this limiting my scope. For instance, only asian/european faces will again make me to search all the database

I am not able to identify which is the right factor to cluster. Any reference to articles or ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: If clustering is what you want: Consider other approaches like FaceNet (face -> euclidean-space embedding; at least one very popular python-based implementation: [openface](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface) which even has this example). For query stuff you probably should more look into other directions, learning to hash and co. Of if you are in metric-space (facenet): approximate nearest-neighbor search.

Comment: Why don't you use the face clustering example program that comes with dlib? http://blog.dlib.net/2017/02/high-quality-face-recognition-with-deep.html.  I assume that's where you saw dlib's chinese whispers code in the first place?

Comment: Thank you  @sascha, yes, it is much more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @Davis King, I'll check it.

Comment: @sascha, Could you please explain me what you meant by "For query stuff .....learning to hash and co". I am sorry, i didn't get you.

Comment: @krishnadamarla Something like [that](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/595d/0fe1c259c02069075d8c687210211908c3ed.pdf) (academic survey pdf link)

Comment: Got it. Thanks @sascha

Comment: @DavisKing, is python version of chineese whispers available for dlib ? i am working with python and i see dlib has only c++ support for this.  Can we do incremental learning with this api http://dlib.net/dlib/clustering/chinese_whispers_abstract.h.html

Comment: Yes: http://dlib.net/face_clustering.py.html

Comment: Thanks @DavisKing, could you please tell me how i can add new faces to http://dlib.net/face_clustering.py.html for incremental learning ?

Answer (score 1):

Clustering in the way i specified in question is not correct for facial images. It is best to use a convolutional neural network to train the features instead of manually computing distances from facial landmarks.

Later on these trained features, we can apply any of the popular clustering algorithm as shown here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.00989.pdf
or as @sascha suggested, Approximate Nearest Neighbour or as @Davis King suggested Chinese Whispers depending on your needs.

As @sascha suggested, there are many deep learning libraries like openface that does this on top of torche/tensorflow.

Comment: I am not quite sure whether it is a classification/clustering problem though. @DavisKing, used chineese whispers clustering in his dlib libraray. Why ? Why not nearest neighbour which is tree based ? One reason could be to use graph based algorithm for fastness. Any other reasons ?  Mabe it depends on our applications ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing clustering on unsupervised data then use face_recognition. Dlib or facial landmarks clusters images based on the facial expressions not on facial features.